# How to find $R(x)$ from washer method?

Tags: calculus

Problem:

> Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the graphs of the equations about the line $y=8$.
> $$\begin{align}y=\sqrt{4-x}\\x=0\\y=0\end{align}$$

My graph:

[image: My graph]

I know that $R(x)$ is $8$, but how would I find $r(x)$? I know how to do the rest. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Note that $R(x) = r(x) + y(x)$, that you can solve for $r(x)$, and that you know formulas for $R(x)$ and $y(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The hole in the washers is actually $r(x)=8-\sqrt{4-x^2}$. You can see in your graph that in the interval $0\leq x \leq 2$, the length of this $r(x)$ will get larger as $x$ gets larger and $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ gets smaller. Also, the point on the bottom of $r(x)$ is on the graph of $y=\sqrt{4-x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

From the graph: $r(x) = 8 - y = 8 - \sqrt{4-x^2}$

Comment: Then, I would do pi * integral from 0 to 2 [8^2 - (8-sqrt(4-x^2))^2]dy.

Comment: Yes, you would.

Comment: I'm still getting the wrong answer after calculating the integral for some reason

Comment: Could you show us your work?

Comment: It would also be helpful to type it out using MathJax too :)

Comment: After integrating, you would get pi(8pi-16/3) = 8pi^2 - 16pi/3

Comment: Just tried it and I'm wondering if we made the same mistake. When you do the trig sub for $\int \sqrt{4-x^2}$ and let $x=2\sin\theta$ and $dx=2\cos\theta \, d\theta$, you should end up with $\int \mathbf{4}\cos^2\theta\,d\theta$. I forgot to multiply the 2 in the $dx$!

Comment: The answer should be $\pi(16\pi-\frac{16}{3})$

Comment: Yes, it still says the wrong answer however

Comment: That's strange... it should've been correct

Comment: What did it say the answer should be?

Comment: It doesn't say unfortunately, I've been stuck on this one for a while now!

Comment: I put the integral into integral-calculator.com and they got $\frac{\pi(48\pi-16)}{3}$ which is the same as our answer. I think their answer is wrong. That happens a lot with these online homework systems -- I've run into that quite a few times myself taking online classes. Maybe ask your professor?